# Get size of serialized Request using Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am using Spring and RestTemplate to send requests to a REST service. Is there a way to get the (byte)size of the actual request? Optimally it includes the size of the HTTP request including the size of the serialized `myObject` object for both GET and POST requests.

```
template.postForObject(restUrl, myObject, MyObject.class);
template.getForObject(restUrl, MyObject.class);
```

Basically I want to know how much data is actually transmitted.

Thanks!

---

[edit]:

Just to complete the answer, this is how you add the Interceptor to the RestTemplate. I also edited the LengthInterceptor to show the content length of the request instead of the response.

```
final List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
interceptors.add( new LengthInterceptor() );
template.setInterceptors( interceptors );
```

Comment: do you mean size of http body or size of raw tcp package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interceptor to intercept the request/response similarly to filter in java servlet. You have to read the response and using `getHeaders().getContentLength()` you'll get the body length:

```
public class LengthInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept( HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution ) throws IOException {

        ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute( request, body );
        long length = response.getHeaders().getContentLength();
        // do something with length
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: and how to deal with chunked request?